# Does the absolute Frobenius induce the identity on étale topoi?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$ and denote by $X_{et}$ its étale topos . Associated to $X,$ we can consider the absolute Frobenius map $F_X: X \rightarrow X$ which gives an associated geometric morphism of étale topoi $F_X: X_{et} \rightarrow X_{et}.$

Is it true that $F_X$ induces the same geometric morphism as the identity $X \rightarrow X$?

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

Let $f\colon U \to X$ be an étale morphism. The absolute Frobenius $U \to U$, the absolute Frobenius $F \colon X \to X$, and the map $f\colon U \to X$ (twice) form a commutative square. This commutative square induces a morphism from $U$ to the fiber product of $U$ and $X$ over $X$ taken with respect to the maps $f$ and $F$, in other words to $F^{-1}(U)$. This morphism is natural and so gives a natural transform from the identity functor from the étale site of $X$ to itself to the absolute Frobenius from the étale site of $X$ to itself.

Because $f$ is étale, this commutative square is in fact Cartesian, so the induced morphism is an isomorphism, and the natural transformation is an isomorphism of functors.

Since $F^{-1}$ is isomorphic as a functor to the identity, their induced geometric morphisms on the topos of sheaves are equivalent.

Comment: This seems to show that the Frobenius is naturally equivalent to the identity. Is this natural equivalence also "relative" to the base? For example, if $X \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_p,$ I have a relative topos $X_{et} \rightarrow (\mathbb{F}_p)_{et}.$ Is then the absolute Frobenius "relatively" isomorphic to the identity?

Comment: @Crystallineperiodic I'm more comfortable with calculations in sites than topoi. Can you express what that means in terms of sites?

Comment: @WillSawin Of course. I think that this paper: https://www.math.ias.edu/vladimir/sites/math.ias.edu.vladimir/files/Etale_topologies_published.pdf in Definition 1.3 gives the correct category I had in mind. I am thus asking if the 2-morphism you give is a 2-morphism in the sense of Def. 1.3(c) of the paper I linked.

Comment: (Where I in the above definition let S be equal to the spectrum of $\mathbb{F}_p.$ )

Comment: Here the only property that is using about étale maps is that they are relatively perfect, thus the same statement holds for the pro-étale site.

Comment: @Crystallineperiodic For $V$ over $\mathbb F_p$ étale, the formula given for $\alpha$ sends $V \times_{\mathbb F_p} X \to (V \times_{\mathbb F_p} X) \times_{X,F} X$  is the obvious map dropping the middle $X$.  To make this natural transformation I wrote down give a 2-morphism, the diagram that has to commute is a pair of morphisms $V \times_{\mathbb F_p } X \to  (V \times_{\mathbb F_p} X) \times_{X, F} X$, one of which is this and the other is the composition of the identity and the map from my answer taking $U = V \times_{\mathbb F_p} X$.

Comment: @Crystallineperiodic I think this diagram does not commute. It suffices to show the two maps do not agree after composition on the left with projection to $V$. For the $\alpha$ map in your link, the composition with projection to $V$ is again the projection to $V$. For my map, this is the composition with the projection to $U$ followed by projection from $U$ to $V$. The composition with the projection to $U$ is the absolute Frobenius $U\to U$, and projection to $V$ composed with absolute Frobenius is the same as absolute Frobenius composed with projection to $V$.

Comment: So the maps differ by an absolute Frobenius, which is nontrivial if $V =\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb F_{p^n}$ for $n>1$.